# MVC3 Dynamic List Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

In MVC3, I've been able to rely on Html.DisplayForModel() to generate display's for my data.  Using this method, and various templates, I have a single View for displaying several of my Models.  What I'm wondering though, is there a way I can get this to work on Lists for my models?

For example, I have a model called Networks.  My view to list out multiple networks looks like this:

```
@model PagedList<Network>

<div id="networkList">
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column => {
        column.For(x => Html.ActionLink(x.Id.ToString(), "NetworkDetails", new { id = x.Id })).Named("Network ID");
        column.For(x => x.Name);
        column.For(x => x.Enabled);
}).Attributes(Style => "text-align: center")

@Html.AjaxPager(Model, new PagerOptions() { PageIndexParameterName="page", ShowDisabledPagerItems = false, AlwaysShowFirstLastPageNumber=true },
                            new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "networkList" })
</div>
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to use a single template when generating lists for my models.  I could rely on attributes to know which properties I would like to generate in my list, ie: [ListItem].

The head scratcher for me is, how can I pass a dynamic model to an extension method?  If it's of any help, the Html.Grid extension is from MVCContrib.  Has anyone else done something similar?  It would be great to rely on a template as it would really chop down on the amount of code.

Comment: Not sure whether this will help you - Can you use @Html.EditorFor() for your model and keep a template to render the Network model.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it for EditorFor() using the following (it might be similar with your Grid extension method assuming it can take the template name parameter):

```
// in the main view
@Html.EditorFor(o => o.InvoiceId, "TemplateName", new { Property = "InvoiceId" })
@Html.EditorFor(o => o.Title, "TemplateName", new { Property = "Title" })

// in the template view
@model object
@{ var property = (string)this.ViewData["Property"]; }
```

Alternatively you can just pass in the name of the template and use this code in the template

```
var prefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
if (prefix.EndsWith("InvoiceId")) { ... }
```

Comment: Gosh, i had to think back on this one as it was an old question.  I never really did find the solution I was hoping for, so i ended up with several views to handle each list of data I was trying to display.  I'm not sure your answer grasps what I was really after though.  The problem is that I can't use an extension method for something that isn't specifically typed.  For well known types, this would be fine, but I was trying to see if I could come up with a generic way for displaying lists of data instead of having a separate view for each type.